# getting date of next christmas using javascript

Tags: javascript

I've a drop-down box in my page as follows:

```
<select id="event_name" style="width:248px;" onchange="updatecollectbasic()" onblur="changecolor()" name="event_name" class="styled">
     <option <? if( $event_name == "") echo 'selected';?> value="">Select</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Birthday") echo 'selected';?> value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Christmas") echo 'selected';?> value="Christmas">Christmas</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Hanukah") echo 'selected';?> value="Hanukah">Hanukah</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Graduation") echo 'selected';?> value="Graduation">Graduation</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Confirmation") echo 'selected';?> value="Confirmation">Confirmation</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Barmitzvah") echo 'selected';?> value="Barmitzvah">Barmitzvah</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Batmiztvah") echo 'selected';?> value="Batmiztvah">Batmiztvah</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Wedding") echo 'selected';?> value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Shower") echo 'selected';?> value="Shower">Shower</option>
         <option <? if( $event_name == "Other") echo 'selected';?> value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
```

and another input box to get the "date" which also has jQuery date-picker attached to it:

```
<input id="event_date" type="text" onchange="updatecollectbasic()" name="event_date" value="<?=$event_date?>" class="inputtext2 table_ip" style="width : 90px;"/>
```

and based on the selection, the date should be choosen, But when the selected option is "christmas", I need to populate the date of christmas in the input field.

for now, i filled that using the script as:

```
if  ($('#event_name').val() == "Christmas") {
                    $('#event_date').val("12/25/2012");
                } else {
                    $('#event_date').val("");
                }
```

but, here what i need is to get the date of christmas as "12/25/2013" as the date passed, similarly after the "12/25/2013" passes and if this selection is made need to show next year's christmas date. How to do it using javascript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include some logic to check where you are in the current year:

```
var d = new Date();
var y = d.getFullYear();
if (d.getMonth() == 11 && d.getDate() > 25)
   y += 1;
$('#event_date').val("12/25/" + y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current month, day, and year using Date() or with server-side code.

If the month is 12 and the day is 26 or greater, return '12/25/current year + 1'
Otherwise return '12/25/current year'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
$('#event_date').val("12/25/2012");
```

Use this :

```
$('#event_date').val("12/25/" + (new Date()).getFullYear());
```

**Note** :

This will be inaccurate from 26th to 31st. See **N Rohler's** answer to avoid it.

Comment: This will be inaccurate on 12/26-12/31 of each year.  See my answer for the full logic.

Comment: @NRohler OP probably knows that... just meant to give the function.